# How to get next auto increment id in SQL

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment, alphanumeric

I have inserted an auto-incremented ID in SQL Server with this code:

```
[EmployeeID] AS ('EMP' + RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT([VARCHAR](5), [UserID]), (5))) + 1 PERSISTED,
```

And I want the next `EmployeeID` like if last inserted record is `EMP0001`, then I want to show `EMP0002` when using a select query.

Comment: What's the purpose? You can't get the next id and store it somewhere and assume it'll be unused when you finally get around to inserting it into the database. If you want to use a database to store unique id's, don't try convoluted methods of generating them. Use an `IDENTITY`, insert a record to "reserve" it and let the database reserve it. Otherwise you have no guarantee the ID is unique when you finally put it in the database.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid. Just want to display before saving in database

Comment: If this is a multi user system, then by the time you have displayed it, someone else has probably got the same number. For example if two people run your code, they get the same number, The first was to insert is OK. The next gets a PK error (or worse... simply inserts a duplicate)

Comment: You can use a `SEQUENCE` to ensure that two users won't get the same number.... _and_ you can just select from it, you don't have to insert. http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-sequence/ The `EMP` part is simply formatting using whatever means.. a calculated column or you could do it in your app.

Answer (score 0):

first put the id column as identity column
after that insert your data. no need to specify id columns it auto increments.
and put identity increment to your initial number and how much it should be incremented is given in identity seed.
check for identity columns in youtube for better understanding.
tq

Answer (score -1):

You need to store `max value` of employee ID in to `declared variable`. From that you will separate `EMP` and `Number`. 
After that you can increase number value by 1 and use `REPLICATE()` for generate preceding `0`.

Please check below query for your answer.

```
DECLARE @EMPID VARCHAR(10)

SELECT
@EMPID = MAX(X.EmployeeID)
FROM
(
SELECT 'EMP0008' EmployeeID UNION ALL
SELECT 'EMP0011'
) X

SELECT 'EMP' + REPLICATE('0',4 - LEN(RIGHT(@EMPID,4) + 1)) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(RIGHT(@EMPID,4) + 1)) AS EmployeeID
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/LIY60904)